# Так вернут ли Монику?

Tags: обсуждение, кризис-2019

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

С момента соглашения прошёл уже месяц. Это значит, что Моника отказалась от восстановления или что?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Моника давала [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/260198) на эту тему:

> I dearly love my communities here, but, sadly, I can't bear to stay on Stack Exchange any longer.

Она решила уйти с SE.

Comment: Так и что делают те, кто менял аватарки и добавлял `says Reinstate Monica`?

Comment: @AK живут дальше!

Comment: @AK ничего. Аватарка больше показывает отношение к компании в целом. Ситуация с Моникой лишь один из примеров их ошибки.

Comment: Давайте навесим этому вопросу метку важное, пусть кто не в курсе узнает.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica это не та информация, которая будет интересна/нужна большей части участников нашего сообщества.

Comment: Тогда как можно "позвать" сюда всех участников ...says Reinstate Monica?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica почти "все" участники даже не знают, кто такая Моника.

Comment: Я имел  ввиду всех участников, которые says Reinstate Monica.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, некоторые из них тоже не знают :)

Comment: @Grundy Кто же, например?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, кто угодно :)

Comment: @Grundy она марионетка FF?

Comment: @yolosora, кто марионетка кого? :)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica а вот кстати информация о вопиющем нарушении лицензии очень даже нужна 100% части участников нашего сообщества во избежание юридических проблем =\

Comment: @andreymal если кто-нибудь сможет написать вопрос с полным разбором ситуации и юридических аспектов.